# Can't change UITableView background color

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have UITableView and I can't change the background of it, I tried a lot but no result.

Every time I try to change its background flips behind it. So, I tried from ViewController by implementing HomeView but also nothing changed.

**HomvView that contain TableView:**

```
class HomeView: UIView {

    var recipes: Recipes?
    var recipesDetails = [Recipe]()
    let indicator = ActivityIndicator()

    let categories = ["italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food"]

    override init( frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layoutUI()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var foodTableView: UITableView = {
        let foodTableView = UITableView()
        foodTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        foodTableView.delegate = self
        foodTableView.dataSource = self
        foodTableView.register(CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell")
        foodTableView.register(HomeTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell")
        foodTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        foodTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        foodTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        return foodTableView
    }()

    func setupFoodTableView() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            foodTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            foodTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            foodTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            foodTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func addSubview() {
        addSubview(foodTableView)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        indicator.setupIndicatorView(self, containerColor: .customDarkGray(), indicatorColor: .white)
        addSubview()
        setupFoodTableView()
        fetchData()

    }

    func fetchData() {
        AF.request("https://apiurl.com").responseJSON { (response) in
            if let error = response.error {
                print(error)
            }
            do {
                if let data = response.data {
                    self.recipes = try JSONDecoder().decode(Recipes.self, from: data)
                    self.recipesDetails = self.recipes?.recipes ?? []
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.foodTableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            self.indicator.hideIndicatorView()
        }
    }

}

extension HomeView: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return recipesDetails.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell
            cell.collectionView.reloadData()
            return cell
        }

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        let url = URL(string: recipesDetails[indexPath.row].image ?? "Error")
        cell.foodImage.kf.setImage(with: url)
        cell.foodTitle.text = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].title
        return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return 160
        }
        return 350
    }

}
```

**UITableViewCell:**

```
class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        layoutUI()
        selectionStyle = .none

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .white
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        return containerView
    }()

    lazy var foodImage: UIImageView = {
        let foodImage = UIImageView()
        foodImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        foodImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        foodImage.clipsToBounds = true
        foodImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        return foodImage
    }()

    lazy var foodTitle: UILabel = {
        let foodTitle = UILabel()
        foodTitle.textColor = .CustomGreen()
        foodTitle.numberOfLines = 0
        foodTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return foodTitle
    }()

    func setupContainerView() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 16),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
        ])
    }

    func setupFoodImage() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            foodImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
            foodImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            foodImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            foodImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250)
        ])
    }

    func setupFoodTitle() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            foodTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foodImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            foodTitle.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
            foodTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            foodTitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),

        ])
    }

    func addSubview() {
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(foodImage)
        containerView.addSubview(foodTitle)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        addSubview()
        setupContainerView()
        setupFoodImage()
        setupFoodTitle()
    }

}
```

What's wrong with my code, please?

Comment: which part did you change the color of the tableView?

Comment: @Joshua In HomeView, `foodTableView.backgroundColor = .gray` but nothing happend

Answer (score 1):

I have try your code and just set 'foodTableView.backgroundColor = .gray' working well. Let do something below and check again.

1. on `layoutUI` add `self.backgroundColor = .red`
2. set `foodTableView.backgroundColor = .gray` when initial
3. run app and check with `Debug View Hierarchy` you can see tableView backgroundColor is gray.

I see you add `containerView` on your cell, so if I right you just want to show `containerView` and transparent color around. 
So let do one little thing. On `layoutUI` of `HomeTableViewCell` clear color of it `self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear` and check again. May be this is your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I should make the cell with clear color, the container with the white color and UITableView with the color I want.

Answer (score 0):

Change the backgroundColor of the tableview and it' cell to the style you want.The color of the palce where the cells display will be the backgroundColor of cell. And the other place will show the backgroundColor of tableview.
If there are 3 cells in a tableveiw, the tableview's backgroundColor is white and the cell's backgroundColor is orange, the color of the cell area will be orange and the color of other tableview area will be white.

Comment: I don't need to change backgroundColor for cell I need it for the TableView and I tried but nothing happend

Comment: @AhmedAbdElaziz I didn't see ur `foodTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.xxx`. I mean since you want to change the color of the tableview, why you didn't add this code?

Comment: @AhmedAbdElaziz What about the number of the cell?If the number of cell is large, you may won't have the chance to see the color of the tableview because the cell just cover the whole area of the tableview. If this happened, then you did change the color of tableview, u just can't see it.

Comment: There are 10 cells when I tried to change TableView background, the background changed but it becomes UIView behind UITableView

Comment: @AhmedAbdElaziz Let me guess...you make a inside cell in the cell and try to make users to think  the the edge of the cell is the background of the tablview, right?